# OpenStack CLI Windows 10 "source" and "venv\Scripts\activate" says not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, windows, command-line, command-line-interface, openstack

I am a beginner trying to use OpenStack CLI on my Windows 10 System. I have tried Python 2.7.18 and 3.9.5. I am able to install the OpenStack client via pip install python-openstackclient but when I try to use my openrc.sh file as a source I get the following "'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." Also do I need to install venv or virtualenv separately? Any help would be appreciated thank you!

Comment: Could you post the steps you are trying to follow? With the specific command that is failing. Also, .sh files are normally bash scripts, so it will probably only run in a linux environment. Source is a linux program, which you will likely not have in windows.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no equivalent command to `source` on Windows system. Anyways, I found this article might help you, I just copied its main content here.

Reference: [Ukcloud - How to use the OpenStackClient on Microsoft operating systems](https://docs.ukcloud.com/articles/openstack/ostack-how-use-cli.html#bind-your-openstack-credentials)

Try this way to use your openrc file:

1. Log in to OpenStack Horizon dashboard
2. Select Access & Security from Compute menu, and then select the API Access tab (or just select API Access tab under Project menu for some versions)
3. Download OpenStack RC File
4. Download [Source-OpenRC.ps1](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/UKCloud/PS-OpenRC/master/Source-OpenRC.ps1) and unblock it
5. Start PowerShell and run `%yourpath%\Source-OpenRC.ps1 %yourpath%\project-openrc.sh`
6. When prompted, enter your OpenStack project password

Answer (score 0):

1. Open powershell, and run:

   ```
   [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('OS_AUTH_URL', 'https://api.pub1.infomaniak.cloud/identity/v3', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
   [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('OS_PROJECT_NAME', 'PROJECT NAME', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
   [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME', 'default', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
   [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('OS_USERNAME', 'USER NAME', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
   [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME', 'default', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
   [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('OS_PROJECT_ID', 'PROJECT ID', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
   [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION', '3', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
   [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('OS_INTERFACE', 'public', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
   [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('OS_REGION_NAME', 'region-name', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
   [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('OS_PASSWORD', 'p@ssw0rd', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
   ```
2. Open **other** powershell and test:

   ```
   openstack image list

   +--------------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------+
   | ID                                   | Name                             | Status |
   +--------------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------+
   | 31341ae7-da5a-42bd-9e6f-920e4839326d | Arch Linux                       | active |
   | 53b05e83-09ec-459c-bbed-dedbdc6b233e | CentOS 7                         | active |
   | a8ce68e0-4adc-4c4b-b668-828ec48fa546 | CentOS 8 Stream                  | active |
   | 80023419-c88c-4067-98be-2eb59a1a2295 | CentOS 9 Stream                  | active |
   | 07729158-3c5e-41f8-810f-b774a83ba566 | Debian 10.12 buster              | active |
   | b51af3cd-f0e4-48cd-ad53-a87f2073d6b5 | Debian 11.3 bullseye             | active |
   | 6728a1a6-cf36-4817-8fc4-c0a0c2b7be04 | Fedora Cloud OS 36               | active |
   | 4732f043-e29f-44bc-89f3-0662261b957f | Fedora Core OS 36                | active |
   | 94777ea5-2d0f-4ed5-8c87-51ada40c5a95 | FreeBSD 13.1                     | active |
   | 01b7ce6e-5f6a-47c3-ad56-be0385698e40 | Infomaniak Rescue Image          | active |
   | d3ddc9bc-fd80-48fe-bc2d-3bbd962f5403 | OPNsense 22.1.2_2-amd64          | active |
   | 236847e3-f3fa-4511-baaf-e4337110a2f0 | RancherOS 1.5.8                  | active |
   | 42aa301c-4097-4046-ba6d-082d90d4033b | Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic Beaver   | active |
   | 107db1f7-f318-4b73-9741-bc5fd1c5a84b | Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Focal Fossa     | active |
   | b1643b50-73b9-4668-b158-b35ae0218c49 | Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Jammy Jellyfish | active |
   | 72e9c1cf-9f1e-4afd-b40b-b2e293827de0 | openSUSE Leap 15.4 JeOS          | active |
   +--------------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------+
   ```